# ng-repeat TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-product-api

I have a sneaking suspicion that I'm missing something basic, but here goes...

**Context**: My server is returning a group of products in the form of objects that contain information that need to be displayed in the browser. I'm using ng-repeat to iterate over these objects (structure of all objects is the same).

**Current State**: The server is returning the objects just fine. They are logged to my console without issue, and in the correct format. However, my browser simply displays:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

**Desire**: I need each of these "products" displayed to the user (using information from the Objects).

Here is my code:

**Object Output** (sample from console)

```
0: Object
    asin: "B001LO9TS8"
    listPrice: "$9.99"
    mediumImage: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Tx19EI3lL._SL160_.jpg"
    offerPrice: "$6.62"
    title: "Gazillion 32 oz Bubbles"
1: Object
    asin: "B00BN4QVF0"
    listPrice: "$8.99"
    mediumImage: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51asVSjyvAL._SL160_.jpg"
    offerPrice: "$5.31"
    title: "Little Kids Fubbles No-Spill Bubble Tumbler, (Colors May Vary)"
```

**Controller File**

```
$scope.getData = function () {
    $scope.success = $scope.error = null;
    var data = $scope.userSearch;
    data.link = link;
    $http.post('/search/data', data).success( function(results) {
        $scope.success = true;
        $scope.results = results;
        console.dir(results);
    }).error( function(results) {
        $scope.error = results.message;
    });
};
```

**HTML File**

```
<div data-ng-show="success" class="text-center col-xs-10">
    <div data-ng-bind="results">
        <div class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat-start="result in results" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img ng-src="{{ result.mediumImage }}" style="max-height: 150px;" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="product-descriptor">Title: </span> {{ result.title }}
                            <hr>
                            <span class="product-descriptor">Price: </span> <del><span style="color: 050505;">{{ result.listPrice }}</span></del> <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">{{ result.price }}</span> -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br ng-repeat-end />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this would cause a problem, but why are you using `ng-repeat-start`/`-end` instead of simply `ng-repeat`?

Comment: $scope.userSearch is defined nowhere, it is null so your post data will be null too. Try adding an input element in your html with the corresponding model.

Comment: @AlexisKing fair question - basically, that was the result of troubleshooting over this problem (trying to narrow down what the issue was).

Comment: @HimmetAvsar good call out - I actually have that as well (just not included in the code above). Since I actually *am* receiving data back from my server, I knew that wasn't the problem, so didn't include the code for the input element/form data.

Comment: @AlexisKing [`ng-repeat-start` and `*-end` has its own purpose](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points). and the usage here is quite legit, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @PSL I know, but it wasn't exactly doing anything here.

Comment: @AlexisKing I was responding to your comment. I think the first commentator is you only LOL... right?

Comment: Actually, it seems ng-repeat-end was doing something here. I removed it from my html (and nothing else) and it broke my page. I put it back in, and life is good. I don't know why. I just started learning angular last week. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) (`<div data-ng-bind="results">`) which is wrapping your subsequent code which is supposed to display the list. ng-bind is causing the list of objects to be stringified and displayed as its textcontent removing all your `ng-repeat` and other code inside of it. You do not need ng-bind for this.

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.results = [{
    asin: "B001LO9TS8",
    listPrice: "$9.99",
    mediumImage: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Tx19EI3lL._SL160_.jpg",
    offerPrice: "$6.62",
    title: "Gazillion 32 oz Bubbles"
  }, {
    asin: "B00BN4QVF0",
    listPrice: "$8.99",
    mediumImage: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51asVSjyvAL._SL160_.jpg",
    offerPrice: "$5.31",
    title: "Little Kids Fubbles No-Spill Bubble Tumbler, (Colors May Vary)"
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div class="text-center col-xs-10">

    <div class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat-start="result in results" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img ng-src="{{ result.mediumImage }}" style="max-height: 150px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="product-descriptor">Title: </span> {{ result.title }}
              <hr>
              <span class="product-descriptor">Price: </span>  <del><span style="color: 050505;">{{ result.listPrice }}</span></del>  <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">{{ result.price }}</span> -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br ng-repeat-end />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that did the trick. Thanks a bunch! I didn't realize those were conflicting.